# Any way to stop UIWebView from opening pdf automatically

Tags: pdf, uiwebview

Is there a way to stop UIWebView from opening PDF files automatically?

Html file that gets loaded is not local and it holds links (href) to some pdf files. Now I would like those files to be downloaded to some local folder on the device instead of being opened by UIWebView by default when the user touches the link buttons.

Is there any way to do this at all? Oh, and if possible without html/xml parsing since I still want to use UIWebView for browsing other pages?

The reason why I don't want UIWebView to open pdf files is because I want my own custom view to do that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method for your web view. Check the `navigationType` for `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` to see if it is a link tapped by the user. Check the URL of the request to see if it is for a PDF file.

If it matches these criteria, then return `NO` from the delegate and do your own processing to download and display the PDF file.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. Worked like a charm.